# Debug and release versions of application work but cannot install it, NET 3.5, C#

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, windows-xp

I've developed app in VS2015 which needs to run on target computers that have Windows XP, NET 3.5. The release and debug versions of the application work without any problems on those computers.

I then made a Setup Project to be able to install the application on target computers and I did so that it requests no additional requirements. I ran the installer on my lap top which is Windows 7 and it works fine but on those target computers I get a message when i try to install the app:

"The installer was interrupted before 'App Name' could be installed.You need to restart the installer to try again."

I tried to find out what is the problem but without a success. I read that it could be problem that I am trying to install an application that was developed in VS2015 and that I need older version, but I couldn't understand why or what to do to make it work. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT1: I've checked and XP computers do have 3.5 NET installed. I also checked the event viewer and error I receive is: "Installation success or error status: 1603"
I've tried the resolutions that Microsoft suggests for this error, but didn't succeed.
EDIT2: I've checked permissions for the installation everything is as should, but still getting the error.

Since I start application from Debug and Release folder directly and it works perfectly, I am sure the problem is in the installer. Any help?

Comment: does the target machines have the framewoek 3.5 installed? Also, have you checked the event viewer on those machines to see if there is any message about why it failed?

Comment: Was this ever resolved? I am facing the exact same issue.